# View the contents of memory footprint of a chrome tab

Tags: google-chrome, out-of-memory

I've got a memory problem in my application. Symptoms are weird: js heap stays stable at around 30 mb, while memory footprint of a browser tab is growing over time out of bounds and eventually crashes entire mac os (I'm looking at memory footprint numbers provided by chrome's task manager). It takes several hours and I can reproduce it consistently. As heap review doesn't give me any clues at all, I'd like to examine the memory allocations for the browser tab, where my application is running. Does chrome provide any tools for that?

Comment: I don't know any tool for that, but the Internet says that it probably detached dom nodes.
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems/
You can find in the link instructions of how to find those